# Build workbench against wall or free standing

Tags: table, workshop

I am building a large workbench (10' x 3') and my original plan was to build it against the wall of the basement.

However, I have no width constraint, so I was thinking maybe it would be better to make it free standing so I could walk around it 360-degrees rather than build it against the wall. This would allow it to be bigger (10' x 4'), on the other hand it would no longer be anchored to wall, so it would be less sturdy.

Is the ability to walk around the bench something I will find very useful for general woodworking and machine work, or would it be better to put it against the wall?

Answer (score 5):

If you have the space, a freestanding workbench away from the wall is a great thing to have. It is much easier to move your body around the bench and workpiece than to rotate the workpiece, particularly when you would rather not disturb its position. You can make it strong with heavy construction (big strong legs).

The drawback is the same as with any workbench, a large flat area upon which to stack stuff... making it unusable, lol...

Comment: Second the vote for freestanding.  Another suggestion, since you stated that you're building it yourself, is to put hefty locking caster wheels underneath the legs, so you can move it around as needed.  If you need more floor space, push it to the wall; if you need 360 access, pull it out.  Wheels on the bottom of the legs shouldn't (in theory) make it any less sturdy.

Comment: I agree with freestanding and wheels, I built my table out of heavy steel plate and welded legs. The only problem it takes 2 car jacks to move it so wheels would be nice, and yes right now it probably has tools stacked a foot high, ++